# Pause all but clicked player (waversurfer+Drupal)

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-8, wavesurfer.js

#### [EDIT: I FITFO on my own, lol – see reply I wrote here]

Ok so I'm going crazy with this for weeks now …

I have multiple instances of Wavesurfer player on my Drupal site.
When I click "play" on one, I want any other currently playing Wavesurfer instances to pause.

I have tried everything I could find, but I can't get it to work.

This is how Drupal implements Wavesurfer:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer = {};

  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.generate = function (context, file, settings) {
    $.each($(context).find('#' + file.id).once('generate-waveform'), function (index, wavecontainer) {
      var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#' + $(wavecontainer).attr('id') + ' .waveform',
        audioRate: settings.audioRate,
        autoCenter: settings.autoCenter,
        barGap: settings.barGap,
        barHeight: settings.barHeight,
        barWidth: settings.barWidth,
        cursorColor: settings.cursorColor,
        cursorWidth: settings.cursorWidth,
        forceDecode: settings.forceDecode,
        normalize: settings.normalize,
        progressColor: settings.progressColor,
        responsive: settings.responsive,
        waveColor: settings.waveColor
      });

      wavesurfer.load(file.path);

      wavesurfer.setVolume(1);

      $(wavecontainer).find('.player-button.playpause').on('click', function (event) {
        Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.PlayPause(wavecontainer, wavesurfer);
      });

      $(wavecontainer).find('.volume').on('change', function (event) {
        wavesurfer.setVolume($(event.currentTarget).val() / 10);
      });

      if (!!settings.autoplay) {
        wavesurfer.on('ready', wavesurfer.play.bind(wavesurfer));
      }
    });
  };


  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.PlayPause = function (wavecontainer, wavesurfer) {
        wavesurfer.playPause();
        var button = $(wavecontainer).find('.player-button.playpause');
        if (wavesurfer.isPlaying()) {
          $(wavecontainer).addClass('playing');
          button.html('<i class="fas fa-pause-circle fa-2x"></i>');
        } else {
          $(wavecontainer).removeClass('playing');
          button.html('<i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>');
        }
      };
```

And this is how I'm currently trying to pause all others:

```
document.addEventListener('playPause', function(e){
    var audios = document.getElementsByClassName('audiofield-wavesurfer');
    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++){
        if(audios[i] != e.target && audios[i].hasClass('playing')){
            audios[i].playPause();
        }
    }
}, true);
```

It seems this won't work (have been reading into Drupal.behaviours and tried modifying that part, also no luck.

I have also tried just letting the PlayPause function run through every player when clicked like this:

```
  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.PlayPause = function (wavecontainer, wavesurfer) {
    $.each($(Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer), function() {
        wavesurfer.playPause();
        var button = $(wavecontainer).find('.player-button.playpause');
        if (wavesurfer.isPlaying()) {
          $(wavecontainer).addClass('playing');
          button.html('<i class="fas fa-pause-circle fa-2x"></i>');
        } else {
          $(wavecontainer).removeClass('playing');
          button.html('<i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>');
        }
      })};
```

… or here:

```
  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.generate = function (context, file, settings) {
    $.each($(context).find('#' + file.id).once('generate-waveform'), function (index, wavecontainer) {
      var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#' + $(wavecontainer).attr('id') + ' .waveform',
        audioRate: settings.audioRate,
        autoCenter: settings.autoCenter,
        barGap: settings.barGap,
        barHeight: settings.barHeight,
        barWidth: settings.barWidth,
        cursorColor: settings.cursorColor,
        cursorWidth: settings.cursorWidth,
        forceDecode: settings.forceDecode,
        normalize: settings.normalize,
        progressColor: settings.progressColor,
        responsive: settings.responsive,
        waveColor: settings.waveColor
      });

      wavesurfer.load(file.path);

      wavesurfer.setVolume(1);

      // ---- HERE MY CODE: --------

      $(wavecontainer).find('.player-button.playpause').on('click', function (event) {
        $.each($(context).find('#' + file.id), function(idx, obj) {
            $(obj).stop();
        });
        Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.PlayPause($(wavecontainer), wavesurfer);
      });
```

but all that didn't work either for me …
does anybody have any idea how to help me figure this out? would save my life!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look and test it yourselves: https://www.ohmniphonic.com/#srvcs

So, for anyone out there trying to FITFO:

After weeks of combing through the Internet, looking for patches, tutorials, or even just clues how to make playPause pause all but the clicked wavesurfer in Drupal (= with strict mode, jQuery, Object Classes, complex scopes/closures, …) I was nearly giving up – but by actually digging deep into it, learning all the new JS/Drupal/etc coding standards and experimenting MASSIVELY with devtools/console/etc, I managed to get it to work. Here's my code:

### JavaScript:

```
// array to store wavesurfers, defined outside function for scope,
const audios = [];

// Start of regular Drupal/wavesurfer function
(function ($, Drupal) {
  'use strict';
  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer = {};
  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.generate = function (context, file, settings) {
    $.each($(context).find('#' + file.id).once('generate-waveform'), function (index, wavecontainer) {
      var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#' + $(wavecontainer).attr('id') + ' .waveform',
        // params
      });

      // […]
      // closure to better access play buttons outside function
      wavesurfer.button = function(wc) {
          return $(wc).find('.player-button.playpause');
      }(wavecontainer);
      
      // used button-closure for this
      $(wavesurfer.button).on('click', function (event) {
            Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.PlayPause($(wavecontainer), wavesurfer);
      });

      // […]
      // add wavesurfer to array.
      audios.push(wavesurfer);
    });
  };

// Custom playPause function
  Drupal.AudiofieldWavesurfer.PlayPause = function (wavecontainer, wavesurfer) {

    // Loop through waveurfers and update classes
    audios.forEach(function(obj) {
        // if it's the audio from the play button
          wavesurfer.playPause();
          if (wavesurfer.isPlaying()) {
            $(wavesurfer.button).html('<i class="fas fa-pause-circle"></i>');
          } else {
            $(wavesurfer.button).html('<i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>');
          }
        } else {
            if (obj.isPlaying()) {
                $(obj.button).html('<i class="fas fa-play-circle"></i>');
                obj.pause();
            }
        }
    });
  };

// […]
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

### CSS:

```
.blazy > .grid {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.playbtn-container {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.player-button {
    font-size: 7em !important;
    height: 98px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block !important;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-left: 0;
    color: #f71735;
    background: white;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -apple-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
}

.player-button:hover {
    font-size: 8em !important;
    height: 112px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    -apple-transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
    transition: all 0.1s ease  0s;
}
```

### HTML (stored as TWIG template in Drupa):

```
<div class="audiofield">
  {% for file in files %}
    <div class="audiofield-wavesurfer" id="wavesurfer_{{ file.id }}">
      <div id="audiofield-audio-player-{{ file.id }}" class="waveform"></div>
      <div class="playbtn-container">
          <div class="player-button playpause play">
              <i class="fas fa-play-circle fa-2x"></i>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

So, in short, the best approach seems storing each wavesurfer in an array and then looping through that array for playPause – something that has also been suggested on the webz, but did not work like that for this context (pun intended, lel) …

Adter nothing else had worked and I had already learned about new variable scopes and such, I did the array idea from scratch, using today's workarounds, tricks, and recommended methods. Most importantly:

1. Defining array outside the Drupal function so it is publicly accessible
2. Creating closure for wavesurfer.button so it becomes a public property

Since I also added some other nice features and FX, I also had to do a bit more, but to keep it simple (for anyone having similar problems) I have reduced the code to what's important.